# Can't read CSV file in an artillery script file

Tags: node.js, testing, load-testing, artillery

I am performing load testing of a microservice and facing an issue while using **Artillery**. Script is failing when reading a csv file. Trying to import input data from a file in order to create a json request.

Simplest **script.yml**:

```
config:
  target: "http://localhost:8080"
  phases:
    - duration: 1
      arrivalRate: 1
  payload:
    path: "input.csv"
    fields:
     - "flow"
scenarios:
  - flow:
     - log: "this yml log, flow: {{ flow }}"
```

**input.csv** file in the same folder:

```
"flow"
"SomeFlow"
```

**simplest command used to execute:**

```
DEBUG=* artillery run script.yml
```

**Error stacktrace:**

```
  artillery:cli Artillery Pro is not installed +0ms
  commands:run defaultOptions:  {
    "_": [
        "run",
        "script.yml"
    ]
} +4ms
/Users/someUser/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:124
          throw new Error(`Invalid Option: from_line must be a     positive integer greater than 0, got ${JSON.stringify(opts.from_line)}`)
      ^
Error: Invalid Option: from_line must be a positive integer greater     than 0, got at new Parser (/Users/someUser/node_modules/csv-    parse/lib/index.js:124:17)
    at parse (/Users/someUser/node_modules/csv-parse/lib/index.js:838:18)
    at readPayloadFile (/Users/someUser/node_modules/artillery/lib/commands/run.js:257:7)
    at /Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:356:13
    at async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:233:13)
    at _asyncMap (/Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:355:9)
    at Object.map (/Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:337:20)
    at readPayload (/Users/someUser/node_modules/artillery/lib/commands/run.js:245:9)
    at fn (/Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:746:34)
    at /Users/someUser/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:1213:16
```

Initially i thought it was a platform specific problem for Windows. Then faced the same problem on OSX. **I definitely miss something minor and important here.**

Comment: For me this just prints `this is a log of the request body: flow`... should it be printing "Someflow " instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like an issue with the latest version. when I downgraded to 1.6.0-24, it worked

Comment: That was silly of me to waste a day. Thank you very much. P.S. I was informed that version 25 is working fine as well